# PHP Missing Files Error

Tags: php

I have a folder named test_codes inside which are an html file(radioButton2.html) meant to submit to a php file(process_radioButton2.php).

The code runs without any output and there is no error message in the error log in the directory.However, when I, out of frustration, went into the general error log, I saw:

> [Fri Jun 26 04:41:58 2015] [error] [client 41.190.3.14] File does not
>   exist: /home/chuzymat/public_html/404.shtml, referer:
>   http://www.chuzymatics.com/test_codes/process_radioButton2.php

Please, what could be wrong? Why is the file invisible even when I am sure it's there?

Comment: Able to run this file http://www.chuzymatics.com/test_codes/process_radioButton2.php. Please make echo exit in file. so you can check

Answer (score 0):

The path to upload directory could be wrong or do not have read/write access. Share your code if you need more exact answers.